# How to Lazy loading in DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, lazy-loading

I want Retrieve big Data from sql server. I want it load row by row and displaying in to DataGridView. That like i execute Sql Script in Sql server management studio 2005. How i do that?!

Comment: no, that like: http://img690.imageshack.us/i/loadingresult.png/. In loading data process i want it display data available on DataGridView

Answer (score 0):

use this query for paging

```
DECLARE @PageIndex int=1
DECLARE @PageSize int=10
DECLARE @StartRow int
DECLARE @EndRow int


SET @StartRow = (@PageSize * (@PageIndex - 1))  + 1  
SET @EndRow = @PageSize * @PageIndex + 1

SET NOCOUNT ON;

WITH ArticleSearch AS
(
    SELECT
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
         (
            -- Dynamic sorting
            ORDER BY       tablename.fieldname 


          ) AS RowNumber,   *


     FROM            tablename

)

-- Statement that executes the CTE
SELECT *
FROM
      ArticleSearch a
WHERE
      a.RowNumber BETWEEN @StartRow AND @EndRow - 1
ORDER BY
      a.RowNumber
```

you can pass pageindex as argument to get which page you want to show and pagesize for total records in each page

Comment: No, I don't want use paging. I wait data must load all on an dataGridView, and in loading process not completed yet, data available must displaying on gid.

Comment: then you must query each row by paging and add each row by row to datagrid

Comment: But that mean data must loaded before post to DataGridView. I want when all data not load completed yet, available data loaded must display on.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `SqlDataReader` to do that, I am quite sure it is used in the SSMS. Every time you read a record (or a batch of records) from the reader, you display it in the user interface.

Do not forget to close the reader after reading is complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can try loading the Data using Backgroundworker class. And in the Progress update call you can update the DataGridview. Also the Progress indicator.

Check these links :

1. http://geeknotes.wordpress.com/2007/09/19/using-backgroundworker-to-update-status/
2. [Using a Background Worker - Update a ProgressBar on the progress of a Recursive Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334799/using-a-background-worker-update-a-progressbar-on-the-progress-of-a-recursive-m)

It contains displaying directories using Backgroundworker.