# How to display a loop's progress without pausing the loop?

Tags: c#, for-loop, backgroundworker, progress

I have a `for` loop (running in its own thread) in which I'm calculating the loop's progress and I want to display the progress value every time it changes, but I want to run the message display command outside the loop, so it doesn't pause the loop.

I have read [How do I display progress during a busy loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194620/how-do-i-display-progress-during-a-busy-loop), but I don't want to use a background worker because I already have one that uses the instance of the class that starts the loop (i.e. I do not want to nest background workers). I am assuming that the alternative would be raising and listening to events, but I am not sure how to implement that in this case.

So, how can I solve this problem without the use of a background worker?

Comment: What do you use: winforms, wpf?

Comment: I use Winforms. Why does that matter?

Comment: Show some code. How much is the for-loop code decoupled from the GUI?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428817/accessing-ui-control-from-backgroundworker-thread-c-sharp  just set the label.Text using Dispatcher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the provided answers didn't meet my requirements, I did some research on events and solved the issue the way I initially wanted.

I declared an event in the class that is starting the loop:

```
public delegate void ProgressChangedEvHandler(int progress);

public event ProgressChangedEvHandler ProgressChanged;

private void OnProgressChanged(int progress)
{
    var handler = ProgressChanged;
    if (handler != null) handler(progress);
}
```

Then I invoked the event from within the loop:

```
for (var index = 0; index < arrayListCount; index++)
{
    var progress = (int) (100*(double) index/(double) arrayListCount);
    OnProgressChanged(progress);
}
```

and then I just created the listener (`LoopClassInstance.ProgressChanged += LoopClassInstance_ProgressChanged;`) in a different class (on a different thread):

```
private void LoopClassInstance_ProgressChanged(int progress)
{
    toolStripProgressBar1.Value = progress;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's Winforms, you can just do a `MyForm.BeginInvoke()` with an anonymous delegate that updates the display of the progress. `BeginInvoke` is asynchronous so it won't block the current thread.

Answer (score 0):

You need to notify something like a *LoopWatcher* out of the loop thread.

```
public class ProgressEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public int Number { get; private set; }
    public ProgressEventArgs(int num)
    {
        this.Number = num;
    }
}

public class Worker
{
    public event EventHandler<ProgressEventArgs> ProgressChanged = delegate { };

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            ProgressChanged(this, new ProgressEventArgs(i));
            Thread.Sleep(1000);   //just an example here
        }
    }
}
```

You can see in `Worker.DoSomething`, there is a loop which costs time. I add an event in `Worker`, so outside the class, the subscriber can know the progress is changed.

```
var worker = new Worker();
worker.ProgressChanged += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Number);
Thread t = new Thread(worker.DoSomething);
t.Start();
```