# Update progress bar from for loop

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

I am processing some xml files in for loop and according to the number of files has been processed I want to show the progress bar. 
Suppose there are 100 files in directory and files are processing one by one in loop and I want to update the progress bar according to the current count of the for loop.
Please suggest..

Comment: update to the iterator in the loop. (if the loop is `for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)` the iterator is i).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use BackgroundWorker combined with a ProgressBar control. Here is a simple [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/83317/BackgroundWorker-and-ProgressBar-demo).

Answer (score 3):

Process the 100 files using a Background Worker, call ReportProgress every iteration,  hook on to the Process changed event of the backgroundworker and update a progressbar accordingly.

You can check out [this tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20220208142948/https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/112547-using-the-backgroundworker-in-c%23/) for details.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class, particularly, at [`ProgressChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx) event.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=1;i<linecount;i++)
{
 progressBar1.Value = i * progressBar1.Maximum / linecount;  //show process bar counts
 LabelTotal.Text = i.ToString() + " of " + linecount; //show number of count in lable
 int presentage = (i * 100) / linecount;
 LabelPresentage.Text = presentage.ToString() + " %"; //show precentage in lable
 Application.DoEvents(); keep form active in every loop
}
```

Comment: Please don't add the [same answer to multiple questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-ad??d-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions). Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates, once you earn enough reputation. If it is not a duplicate, tailor the post to the question

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Sorry i am new here.thanks for the advice and i will follow in future.

Answer (score 0):

> Set Minimum and Maximum and then use the `Step` property with the `PerformStep` method to increment the value of the ProgressBar.

```
 progressBar1.Step = 1;
 int part=someList.Count / 100;
 ....
 .... 
 //Inside the loop 

  if (loop_counter % part == 0)
  {
       progressBar1.PerformStep();
  }
```

[See](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.progressbar?view=netcore-3.1)